# HttpClient- No mediatypeformatter is available to read an object of type 'Model'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, httpclient, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using httpclient with .net core 2.1. Now the issue is when I am trying to fetch data from url I am getting the error "No mediatypeformatter is available to read an object of type 'Model'". The code is working fine on other places but here I am getting an exception. Here is the code:

```
            string url = uri;
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(somestring);
            _httpClient.DefaultHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyModel>();
```

If I use response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() and deserialize the string using JsonConvert than it works fine but I think _httpClient is not that flexible. I also faced this issue a long time before while using restsharp but then I used "application/json; charset=utf-8" and it started working fine. So is there way to add charset=utf-8 in httpclient content-type header?

Comment: What is the reference did you use for `_httpClient.DefaultHeaders` and `Content.ReadAsAsync`? I made a test with `HttpClient` in `Core 2.1`.I need to reference `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` to use `Content.ReadAsAsync` and there is only `DefaultRequestHeaders` instead of `DefaultHeaders`. I fail to reproduce your issue my code in answer.

Answer (score -1):

I made a test with code below which works, I suggest you make a test:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.GetAsync(@"https://localhost:44342/Products");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
```

Since it works with `JsonConvert`, I would suggest you try to implement extension method for `Content` for a workaround.

```
public static class HttpContentExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<T> ReadAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpContent content)
        {
            string json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            T value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            return value;
        }
    }
```